How to expand layout in motion layout in 2 steps?
Now the animation works perfectly.
But it’s a bit unsuitable for me, since when I scroll a vertical nestedscrollview, the toolbar_image immediately expands.
How can we make it so that when we scroll down first, the nestedscrollview reached top and we get to the beginning of contents, and if after that we scroll down (drag down) again, so that the toolbar_image expands, and does not immediately open.
I implemented this, without using MotionLayout, using CoordinatorLayout, also with ObjectAnimator and checking (!nestedScrollView.canScrollVertically(-1)) in the MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE method.
But I want to implement this using MotionLayout and MotionScene:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        app:constraintSetEnd="@id/collapsed"
        app:constraintSetStart="@id/expanded">

        <OnSwipe
            app:dragDirection="dragUp"
            app:touchAnchorId="@id/nestedScrollView"
            app:touchAnchorSide="top"/>

        <KeyFrameSet>
            <KeyAttribute
                app:framePosition="60"
                app:motionTarget="@id/toolbar_image">
                <CustomAttribute
                    app:attributeName="imageAlpha"
                    app:customIntegerValue="255" />
            </KeyAttribute>
            <KeyAttribute
                app:framePosition="90"
                app:motionTarget="@id/toolbar_image">
                <CustomAttribute
                    app:attributeName="imageAlpha"
                    app:customIntegerValue="0" />
            </KeyAttribute>
            <KeyPosition
                app:keyPositionType="pathRelative"
                app:framePosition="50"
                app:motionTarget="@id/title"
                app:percentX="0.9" />
        </KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/expanded">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/toolbar_image"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:scaleX="1.0"
            android:scaleY="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar_image"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/collapsed">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/toolbar_image"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/title"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleX="0.625"
            android:scaleY="0.625"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar_image"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/toolbar_image" />

    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>

Now

Expected

